# How to return a value from the function to the program?

Tags: c, function, return

I used a function to ask for input from the user, then after the function I used `if-else` statement so that if the user entered a wrong data type it would ask to enter to input again, but it tells me the variable is uninitialized, how can i fix this?

This is the `if-else` segment of my code :

```
menu();
    
if (isdigit(menuChoice) == 0) {
    menu();
}
```

And this is the function:

```
void menu()
{
    char menuChoice;
    printf("Hello, how may i help you?\n");
    printf("1. Enter today's input and view reports.\n");
    printf("2. Exit the program.\n");
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%c", &menuChoice);
    return menuChoice;
}
```

Comment: This would have issued a warning from the compiler. Read them. They are there to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify return type other than `void` to have functions return values.

For example,

```
char menu() /* use char instead of void */
{
    char menuChoice;
    printf("Hello, how may i help you?\n");
    printf("1. Enter today's input and view reports.\n");
    printf("2. Exit the program.\n");
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%c", &menuChoice);
    return menuChoice;
}
```

Then, have it catch (assign to variable in this case) what is returned.

```
menuChoice = menu();
    
if (isdigit(menuChoice) == 0) {
    menuChoice = menu();
}
```